# Multithreading and heap corruption

Tags: c++, multithreading, heap-memory, sfml, heap-corruption

So I just started trying out some multithreaded programming for the first time, and I've run into this heap corruption problem. Basically the program will run for some random length of time (as short as 2 seconds, as long as 200) before crashing and spitting out a heap corruption error. Everything I've read on the subject says its very hard thing to diagnose, since the what triggers the error often has little to do with what actually causes it. As such, I remain stumped.

I haven't been formally taught multithreading however, so I was mostly programming off of what I understood of the concept, and my code may be completely wrong. So here's a basic rundown of what I'm trying to do and how the program currently tries to handle it:

I'm writing code for a simple game that involves drawing several parallaxing layers of background. These levels are very large (eg 20000x5000 pixels), so obviously trying to load 3 layers of those sized images is not feasible (if not impossible). So currently the images are split up into 500x500 images and I have the code only have the images it immediately needs to display held in memory. Any images it has loaded that it no longer needs are removed from memory. However, in a single thread, this causes the program to hang significantly while waiting for the image to load before continuing.

This is where multithreading seemed logical to me. I wanted the program to do the loading it needed to do, without affecting the smoothness of the game, as long as the image was loaded by the time it was actually needed. So here is how I have it organized:

1.) All the data for where the images should go and any data associated with them is all stored in one multidimensional array, but initially no image data is loaded. Each frame, the code checks each position on the array, and tests if the spot where the image should go is within some radius of the player.

2.) If it is, it flags this spot as needing to be loaded. A pointer to where the image should be loaded into is push_back()'d onto a vector.

3.) The second thread is started once the level begins. This thread is initially passed a pointer to the aforementioned vector.

4.) This thread is put into an infinite While loop (which by itself sounds wrong) that only terminates when the thread is terminated. This loop continuously checks if there are any elements in the vector. If there are, it grabs the 0th element, loads the image data into that pointer, then .erase()'s the element from the vector.

That's pretty much a rundown of how it works. My uneducated assumption is that the 2 threads collide at some point trying to write and delete in the same space at once or something. Given that I'm new to this I'm certain this method is terrible to some embarrassing degree, so I'm eager to hear what I should improve upon.

EDIT:  Adding source code upon request:

```c
class ImageLoadQueue
{
private:
ImageHandle* image;
std::string path;
int frameWidth, frameHeight, numOfFrames;
public:
ImageLoadQueue();
ImageLoadQueue(ImageHandle* a, std::string b, int c, int d, int e=1) { setData(a,b,c,d,e); }

void setData(ImageHandle* a, std::string b, int c, int d, int e=1)
{
    image = a;
    path = b;
    frameWidth = c;
    frameHeight = d;
    numOfFrames = e;
}
void loadThisImage() { image->loadImage(path, frameWidth, frameHeight, numOfFrames, numOfFrames); }
};

class ImageLoadThread : public sf::Thread
{
private:
std::vector<ImageLoadQueue*>* images;

public:
ImageLoadThread() { };
ImageLoadThread(std::vector<ImageLoadQueue*>* a) { linkVector(a); }

void linkVector(std::vector<ImageLoadQueue*>* a) { images = a; }
virtual void Run()
{
    while (1==1)
    {

        if (!images->empty())
        {
            (*images)[0]->loadThisImage();
            images->erase(images->begin());     
        }
    }
}

};


class LevelArt
{
private:
int levelWidth, levelHeight, startX, startY, numOfLayers;
float widthScale, heightScale, widthOfSegs, heightOfSegs;
float* parallaxFactor;
ImageHandle** levelImages;
int** frame;
int** numOfFrames;
bool* tileLayer;
bool** isLoaded;
Animation** animData;
std::string** imagePath;

std::vector<ImageLoadQueue*> imageQueue;
ImageLoadThread imageThread;

 public:
LevelArt(void);
LevelArt(std::string);
~LevelArt(void);

void loadData(std::string);
void drawLevel(sf::RenderWindow*, float, float);
void scaleLevel(float, float);
void forceDraw(sf::RenderWindow*);
void wipeLevel();
void initialLoad();

int getLevelWidth() { return levelWidth; }
int getLevelHeight() { return levelHeight; }
int getTotalWidth() { return widthOfSegs*levelWidth; }
int getTotalHeight() { return heightOfSegs*levelHeight; }
int getStartX() { return startX; }
int getStartY() { return startY; }
};
```

That's most of the relevant threading code, in this header.  Within the levelArt.cpp file exists 3 nested for loops to iterate through all the levelArt data stored, testing if they exist close enough to the player to be displayed, wherein it calls:

```
imageQueue.push_back(new ImageLoadQueue(&levelImages[i][(j*levelWidth)+k], imagePath[i][(j*levelWidth)+k], widthOfSegs, heightOfSegs, numOfFrames[i][(j*levelWidth)+k]));
```

i,j,k being the for loop iterators.

Comment: It's pretty hard to diagnose a problem with a program without the source code.

Comment: Well I can post the source code if I need to, but I'm wondering if what I'm attempting concept-wise is solid or not.  I'll try dig out the relevant parts of the code though, will post shortly.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a reasonable use of multithreading.  The key idea (in other words, the main place you'll have problems if you do it wrong) is that you have to be careful about data that is used by more than one thread.

You have two places where you have such data:

1. The vector (which, by the way, should probably be a queue)
2. The array where you return the data

One way to arrange things - by no means the only one - would be to wrap each of these into its own class (e.g., a class that has a member variable of the vector).  Don't allow any direct access to the vector, only through methods on the class.  Then synchronize the methods, for example using a mutex or whatever the appropriate synchronization object is.  Note that you're synchronizing access to the object, not just the individual methods.  So it's not enough to put a mutex in the "read from queue" method; you need a common mutex in the "read from queue" and "write to queue" methods so that no one is doing one while the other occurs.  (Also note I'm using the term mutex; that may be a very wrong thing to use depending on your platform and the exact situation.  I would likely use a semaphore and a critical section on Windows.)

Synchronization will make the program thread-safe.  That's different than making the program efficient.  To do that, you probably want a semaphore that represents the number of items in the queue, and have your "load data thread" wait on that semaphore, rather than doing a while loop.

Comment: Thank you!  Not wholly familiar with mutexes or semaphores, so looks like I have some homework to do.

Comment: Just found that the SFML I've been using totally includes mutex stuff and I must have skipped over it before some reason, no wonder I'm having problems.  It seems pretty easy to implement so I'm probably good to go now.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @ChrisDilley - yup - read the stuff on mutex, semaphore, event, criticalSection. lock, monitor, condvars etc. - mastering these primitives is absoultely essential for safe and efficient inter-thread comms.  Managing a producer-consumer queue with a criticalSection and a semaphore is vastly more efficient than polling - as pointed out by Michael - +1